# Abstract algebra in cryptography

Tags: encryption

I have taken a course in my undergraduate on the theory part of abstract algebra.Now am interested to know how can abstract algebra be applied to cryptography.Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest reading an introductory book on crypto then trying to ask more specific questions. As is, the question is to broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow that's a broad question. The shortest answer is that lots of Public Key Cryptography is based around a collection of mathematical problems that we believe are hard to solve. Why do we believe they're hard to solve? Because they're age-old Algebra (well, normally Number Theory actually but still) problems that mathematicians and computer scientists have been trying to find efficient solutions to for a long time.

The first two examples you're likely to come across are the [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) and the [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29) scheme. In the case of D-H, the mathematical problem underlying it is a group theory issue, known as the [DHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_problem), and for RSA it's a number theoretical assumption known (unsurprisingly) as the [RSA assumption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_problem)